# Symmetric ds skipping batches issue

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, database-replication, symmetricds, symmetric

I'm facing an Skipping batches issues with my symmetric ds setup,don't know the exact reason behind this because its not having the same pattern but when this event happened the data getting mismatched/missing between server & client DB.

**Logs:**

2021-11-08 11:15:43,009 ERROR [corp-000] [AcknowledgeService] [qtp224591451-2867467] Could not find batch 001-315947 to acknowledge as OK

2021-11-08 11:15:43,020 ERROR [corp-000] [AcknowledgeService] [qtp224591451-2867467] Could not find batch 001-315950 to acknowledge as OK

2021-11-08 11:15:43,034 ERROR [corp-000] [AcknowledgeService] [qtp224591451-2867467] Could not find batch 001-315954 to acknowledge as OK

2021-11-08 11:15:43,049 ERROR [corp-000] [AcknowledgeService] [qtp224591451-2867467] Could not find batch 001-315957 to acknowledge as OK

2021-11-08 11:15:43,061 ERROR [corp-000] [AcknowledgeService] [qtp224591451-2867467] Could not find batch 001-315960 to acknowledge as OK
2021-11-08 11:15:43,134 INFO [corp-000] [PullUriHandler] [qtp224591451-2859551] 717 data and 5 batches sent during pull request from store1:001:001
2021-11-08 11:15:43,136 INFO [store-001] [IncomingBatchService] [store-001-dataloader-27054] Skipping batch 000-315947 that was already loaded

2021-11-08 11:15:43,140 INFO [store-001] [IncomingBatchService] [store-001-dataloader-27054] Skipping batch 000-315950 that was already loaded

2021-11-08 11:15:43,151 INFO [store-001] [IncomingBatchService] [store-001-dataloader-27054] Skipping batch 000-315954 that was already loaded

2021-11-08 11:15:43,155 INFO [store-001] [IncomingBatchService] [store-001-dataloader-27054] Skipping batch 000-315957 that was already loaded

2021-11-08 11:15:43,159 INFO [store-001] [IncomingBatchService] [store-001-dataloader-27054] Skipping batch 000-315960 that was already loaded

**Source DB-postgres**

**Destination DB-MS SQL**

**SymmetricDS version: 3.10.13**

Maybe someone know why its happen?
Please let me know if you want any other info related configuration.
Thanks !!!

Comment: What’s in the table sym_outgoing_batch at the source server?

Comment: You mean batch_id details right? @BorisPavlović


`demo=# select * from sym_outgoing_batch where batch_id=315950;
(0 rows)`

`demo=# select * from sym_outgoing_batch where batch_id=315957;
(0 rows)`

`demo=# select * from sym_outgoing_batch where batch_id=315960;
(0 rows)`

`demo=# select * from sym_outgoing_batch where batch_id=315954;
(0 rows)`

Comment: Not details about one batch but a range of outgoing batches to see if at the source some have been missed to be created

Comment: OK done the main issues are with my connection pooling setup.

I have pgpool connection pooling tool with database load balancing setting enabled but due to the false configuration setup Symmetric ds operations were going on the standby nodes instead of the Primary, that causes an issues and that's why Symmetric DS throwing errors like above.
Thank You!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK done the main issues are with my connection pooling setup.

I have pgpool connection pooling tool with database load balancing setting enabled but due to the false configuration setup Symmetric ds operations were going on the standby nodes instead of the Primary, that causes an issues and that's why Symmetric DS throwing errors like above.

Thank You!!